# Java convert short to byte[] issue in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    short sh = 100;
    printBytesString(shortToBytes1(sh));
    System.out.println();
    printBytesString(shortToBytes2(sh));
}

public static byte[] shortToBytes1(short sNum) {
    byte[] bytesRet = new byte[2];
    bytesRet[0] = (byte)((sNum >> 8) & 0xFF);
    bytesRet[1] = (byte)(sNum & 0xFF);
    return bytesRet;
}

public static byte[] shortToBytes2(short sNum) {
    byte[] bytesRet = new byte[2];
    bytesRet[0] = (byte)(sNum >> 8);
    bytesRet[1] = (byte)(sNum);
    return bytesRet;
}
```

Output:
0000000001100100
0000000001100100

The result is the same. so, what's the difference between shortToBytes1() and shortToBytes2() ?

Comment: Can you explain what you think (sNum >>) & 0xFF differs from sNum >> 8?  This is important if you want to decide which to use in different situations.

Comment: You might be interested in http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Shorts.html#toByteArray(short) .

Comment: I don't think "what's the difference?" is the question you really wanted to ask. You will most likely get some glib answers. If perhaps you had rephrased it as "I expected X to happen, but Y happens, and I'm not sure why, even after I read up about `short` and `byte` and `>>` and `&`, can someone explain?" you should get a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

`shortToBytes1` converts the bytes their unsigned int value first while the second does not. I would recommend using the first.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I mean even if the shortToBytes2() does't conevert the bytes their unsigned int value first, the result is still ok. So why the shortToBytes1() is needed.